# How do I express this ORDER BY clause in JPA?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, sql-order-by, jpa-2.0

I'm using JPA 2.0, Hibernate 4.1.0.Final, and MySQL 5.5.27.  I'm trying to convert a native MySQL query to a CriteriaBuilder query.

```
    final Query query = m_entityManager.createNativeQuery(
            "SELECT user_name FROM users WHERE user_name like ? ORDER BY convert(REPLACE(user_name, ?, ''), signed) DESC LIMIT 1")
            .setParameter(1, userNamePrefix.toLowerCase() + "%")
            .setParameter(2, userNamePrefix);
```

I'm able to figure out every part except the "ORDER BY" part of my clause.  Here is the converted query without the ORDER BY clause ...

```
    final CriteriaBuilder builder = m_entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    final CriteriaQuery<User> criteria = builder.createQuery(User.class);
    final Root<User> user = criteria.from(User.class);
    criteria.where(builder.like(user.get(User_.userName), username + "%"));
    final TypedQuery<User> query = m_entityManager.createQuery(criteria);
```

Any ideas how I write "ORDER BY convert(REPLACE(user_name, ?, ''), signed)" as JPA?

**Edit:** I'm trying the "function" suggestion, below, but there doesn't seem to be a way to get the "Signed" part of the function to come out without quotes.  I tried the below ...

```
    final Expression<String> usernamePrefixExpr = builder.literal(userNamePrefix);
    final Expression<String> emptyStrExpr = builder.literal("");
    final Expression<String> replaceFn = builder.function("REPLACE", String.class, user.get(User_.userName), usernamePrefixExpr, emptyStrExpr);
    final Expression<String> signedExpr = builder.literal("signed");
    final Expression<String> convertExpr = builder.function("CONVERT", String.class, replaceFn, signedExpr);
    criteria.orderBy(builder.desc(convertExpr));
```

but "signed" is replaced with "'signed'", which doesn't work.

Comment: Why not to stay with the native query? I think if you use a mysql specific function, there is not advantage not to use the native query (I think native query support is implemented just for that kind of issues)

Answer (score 0):

It will be ugly, but you should be able to do this with CriteriaBuilder 'function()' method.

Comment: I tried the "function" but I can't seem to be able to accurately translate the "signed" portion of my expression.

Comment: I think the problem with the `function` approach is that it assumes all function arguments are expressions that finally evaluate to an int or string or something similar, but not to a keyword. Another really ugly approach could be to encapsulate the cast into an mysql function e. g. names `castStringToInt`, and then call that via JPA `function` syntax. But apart from adding dependency on the stored function, this would possibly have a bad effect on performance in case of large result sets.

Comment: Is this "castStringToInt" function something I would write or is there something built-in to MySQL that I could use?  I'd prefer not to write any custom MySQL code but if that's the only solution here so be it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `replaceFn.as(Integer.class)` instead of `builder.function("CONVERT", String.class, replaceFn, signedExpr)` to change the code of the last code block in the question to:

```
final Expression<String> usernamePrefixExpr = builder.literal(userNamePrefix);
final Expression<String> emptyStrExpr = builder.literal("");
final Expression<String> replaceFn = builder.function("REPLACE", String.class, user.get(User_.userName), usernamePrefixExpr, emptyStrExpr);
final Expression<Integer> convertedExpr = replaceFn.as(Integer.class);
criteria.orderBy(builder.desc(convertedExpr));
```

**Edit**
This will possibly not work, as the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Expression.html#as%28java.lang.Class%29) states "the runtime type is not changed".

Comment: Hi, I don't understand what you mean.  What will the Java code become?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  When running this, I get the Hibernate runtime exception, "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: cast() requires two arguments [select generatedAlias0 from org.mainco.subco.user.domain.User as generatedAlias0 where ( generatedAlias0.userName like :param0 ) and ( generatedAlias0.url=:param1 ) order by cast(REPLACE(generatedAlias0.userName, :param2, :param3) as integer) desc]".